# How to avoid duplicate rows while inserting a set of row from flatfile in SQL SERVER by considering existing column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with set of rows with same RecordtypeCode,

[image]

then the single/set row coming from a flatfile/other source like below,
[image]

finally I need a unique row in my table by elimating the duplicate Recordtypecode & taking the max of other field information,

Finally my table should like this,
[image]

What I tried right now?
     Fetching all the rows from my table & then union with the new set of records then wrote the stored procedure (using group by & max keyword) to get the desired output in temp table & finally truncate my table & then insert the temp table data to my table.

Is there is any other better ways to avoid performance issue, because i am going to play with millions of records here.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without more details, but you could try something like this to get grouped results:

```
SELECT RecordTypeCode, 
       Max(AgeGroupFemale60_64), 
       Max(AgeGroupFemale65_69), 
       Max(AgeGroupFemale70_74)
FROM [TempTable]
GROUP BY RecordTypeCode
```

Comment: I used same query to achieve it, my concern is to remove the duplicate from the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+, you could use `MAX() OVER` to determine maximum flag values within every `Recordtypecode` group:

```
SELECT
  Recordtypecode,
  AgeGroupFemale60_64,
  AgeGroupFemale65_69,
  AgeGroupFemale70_74,
  MAX(AgeGroupFemale60_64) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode),
  MAX(AgeGroupFemale65_69) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode),
  MAX(AgeGroupFemale70_74) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode)
FROM
  dbo.TempTable
```

and update all the flags with those values:

```
WITH maximums AS (
  SELECT
    Recordtypecode,
    AgeGroupFemale60_64,
    AgeGroupFemale65_69,
    AgeGroupFemale70_74,
    MaxFemale60_64 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale60_64) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode),
    MaxFemale65_69 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale65_69) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode),
    MaxFemale70_74 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale70_74) OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode)
  FROM
    dbo.TempTable
)
UPDATE
  maximums
SET
  AgeGroupFemale60_64 = MaxFemale60_64,
  AgeGroupFemale65_69 = MaxFemale65_69,
  AgeGroupFemale70_74 = MaxFemale70_74
;
```

Next, you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate all the rows within the groups:

```
SELECT
  *
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode ORDER BY Recordtypecode)
FROM
  dbo.TempTable
```

and delete all the rows with `rn > 1`:

```
WITH enumerated AS (
  SELECT
    *
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode ORDER BY Recordtypecode)
  FROM
    dbo.TempTable
)
DELETE FROM
  enumerated
WHERE
  rn > 1
;
```

Alternatively, instead of the two statements, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, you could use one, `MERGE` (which now assumes SQL Server 2008+), like this:

```
WITH enumerated AS (
  SELECT
    *
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Recordtypecode ORDER BY Recordtypecode)
  FROM
    dbo.TempTable
),
maximums AS (
  SELECT
    Recordtypecode,
    MaxFemale60_64 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale60_64),
    MaxFemale65_69 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale65_69),
    MaxFemale70_74 = MAX(AgeGroupFemale70_74),
    rn = 1
  FROM
    dbo.TempTable
  GROUP BY
    Recordtypecode
)
MERGE INTO
  enumerated AS tgt
USING
   maximums AS src
ON
  tgt.Recordtypecode = src.Recordtypecode AND tgt.rn = src.rn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    tgt.AgeGroupFemale60_64 = src.MaxFemale60_64,
    tgt.AgeGroupFemale65_69 = src.MaxFemale65_69,
    tgt.AgeGroupFemale70_74 = src.MaxFemale70_74
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  DELETE
;
```

More information:

1. [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
2. [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

   Note that there are known issues with the MERGE statement that you need to be aware before deciding to use it. You can start with this article to learn more about them and see whether any of them would apply to your situation:

   - [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)